# .htaccess - question mark

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to get a `path` string, but I need it's entirety. I handle that through a `.htacces` file, it works fine, accept for question marks.

**Question:** Can you get the `path` value including question marks?

*I have tried:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

*Example:*

```
http://example.com/something?
```

*Result*

```
something
```

**Wanted result**

```
something?
```

That is without the questions mark, is there any way to do that? I have tried researching, I haven't found anything so far. I'm assuming it needs to be some kind of tag in `[]` those parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid interfering with the query string, use:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$). index.php [NS,L,DPI]
```

…and, in `index.php`, parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to see what page was requested.

Comment: *anndd..* this is why I ask questions here, beautiful answer! Thank you.